# Where was the attacking boat?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

In Return Of The Jedi, during the battle over the Sarlacc, Luke is fighting some goons with his lightsaber on the sail barge or another skiff (I can't remember). Boba Fett is standing on a skiff aiming his wrist-mounted rocket launcher at Luke and Han Solo is lying unconscious behind him. Han Solo yells

> "Boat attack? Boat attack, where?"

and gets up while holding a plank and accidentally hits Boba Fett, turning on his jetpack, which throws him in the pit, incapacitating him.

Where was this attacking skiff and who informed him of it? It is kind of weird that he said that even though no skiff attacked Han Solo's skiff.

Comment: This is a glorious example of a Mondegreen.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen

Comment: That scene is here: https://youtu.be/nAnkFVaKnec?t=244. To be fair, the audio quality of those lines is very poor: Han Solo's voice is covered by the music and the sounds of the fight, and he doesn't even speak clearly.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Han is saying "Boba Fett? Boba Fett, where?" He's responding to Chewbacca, who's presumably saying "watch out, it's Boba Fett!"

Subtitled on Disney+:
[image: Screengrab from Return of the Jedi on Disney+, showing Boba Fett aiming at Luke Skywalker, and subtitled "Boba Fett? Where?"]

Comment: Isn't that the only time that Boba Fett's name is actually said aloud in the original trilogy?

Comment: Oh, I swear he was saying "boat attack" but oh well. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @tbrookside I just searched through the scripts and you're right, it is. The only other mentions are in stage directions. He does introduce himself by name in the _Holiday Special_ though.

Comment: @Withad The "Special" of which you speak does not exist. It never existed. It was not real. It was the delusional mass dream that never happened. I do not have a copy on VHS in a cabinet. It is not part of Weird Al's White & Nerdy video. We shall never speak of it again.

**heads off to video cabinet to find tape to watch again**

Comment: @Withad That's what I thought.  It's funny that Boba Fett was already a legend before ROTJ came out...even though his name was never given to the audience during his first appearance.

Comment: @tbrookside It would have also been on merchandise like toys, so many of the audience likely would have known the name,

Comment: @tbrookside Actually, the *Holiday Special* (1978) **was** Boba Fett's first appearance, since it came out 2 years before *Empire Strikes Back* (1980).

Comment: @BBlake, and you can't watch it Riffed at https://www.rifftrax.com/the-star-wars-holiday-special

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Ah, OK.  That makes sense...I have never seen the Holiday Special.  Is it any good?

Comment: @tbrookside: Boba Fett's appearance in a cartoon during the special is about the only part of it that's even vaguely watchable. The rest is only enjoyable to the most hardened of masochists. People watched it because they wanted more Star Wars. It was never released on VHS because it was embarrassingly bad.

Comment: @tbrookside George Lucas is on the record saying that he would personally burn every copy of it if he could.  If you're curious, watch some reviews of it on YouTube, or the Rifftrax version.  I couldn't imagine anyone wanting to watch it straight.  I wouldn't say that the Boba Fett part is the *only* scene that's watchable - the Bea Arthur musical number wasn't terrible.  (Yes, there's a Bea Arthur musical number in it - that should give you an idea what you're getting into.)  But yeah, it's otherwise a bit of a train wreck.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman In 1977 there was a [commercial for the Boba Fett action figure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SITR9K-8PXY). I remember wondering if I'd missed something, since why would there be an action figure for a character we'd never heard of?

Comment: Isn't Boba Fett shown standing near Jabba in ANH? Or is it a retcon?

Comment: @TimSparrow: It's a double-retcon. There *was* an original scene filmed for Jabba, but it wasn't released in theatres (they just had a hefty dude playing the part, and technology didn't let them replace him with a creature until the special edition rereleases decades later; even then, the scene was broken, because Han walked around the actor in a way that wouldn't work with Jabba, so they had to clumsily make it look like Han stepped on CGI Jabba's tail). But that scene didn't have Boba Fett in it when it was filmed, not even a stand-in for him; he was inserted into it from scratch.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes, I saw that scene in 'deleted materials' (the original, with an actor for Jabba), and how they changed it from release to release.